# Javascript .filter is not completely filtering my array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just recently started trying to learn Javascript, and am writing some code for my mother (who is a teacher) to randomly assign desk numbers for peer grading. The code should take in a class period (each period has different desk numbers that are always empty) as well as the desk number(s) of student(s) who are absent that day. Right now, I'm trying to then create an array of desk numbers which are available to be assigned to grade.

However, although the absent student numbers are correctly included in the totalMissingDesks array, they are not filtered out of the availableDesks array. Does anyone have an idea why?

```
//Set up necessary variables
  const totalDesks = 30;
  const period = document.getElementById("class-period").value;
  const absentStudents= [document.getElementById("absent-students").value];
  let missingDesksPerPeriod = [[0],[2,17],[4],[1,15,22],[7,29],[4,22],[3,18],[2,12],];

  //Create array of all desk numbers
  let deskNumbers = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalDesks; i++) {
     deskNumbers.push(i);
  };

  //Create more arrays
  const alwaysMissingDesks = missingDesksPerPeriod[period];   //desks that are always missing based on class period
  const todayMissingDesks = absentStudents;                   //desks that are missing due to absent students
  const totalMissingDesks = alwaysMissingDesks.concat(todayMissingDesks);   //concatenate together all missing desks

  //Create arrays of all desks available to be assigned. NOTE THAT THIS DOESN'T FILTER OUT ABSENT STUDENTS RIGHT NOW
  const availableDesks = deskNumbers.filter(function(x) {
    return !totalMissingDesks.includes(x);
  });
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is no way to tell what is values for variables `period`, `absentStudents`, etc.

Comment: Fetching the `.value` properties of `<input>` elements will give you **strings**, not numbers. The `.incudes()` function will perform `===` comparisons, so the string "2" is not equal to the number 2.